# Sequence of dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

I need all days a patient is in the hospital , days between AufnDat and EntlDat. I use seq with mutate  as shown in the reprex I get the error:
Error in seq.Date(from = dmy(AufnDat), to = dmy(EntlDat), by = "day"): 'from' muss Länge 1 haben

````
    ``` r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~PLZ,     ~AufnDat,     ~EntlDat, ~Stat1,
        67067, "22.01.2020", "23.01.2020",   "1A",
        74936, "21.01.2020", "23.01.2020",   "1A",
        97999, "21.01.2020", "27.01.2020",   "0A",
        76669, "15.01.2020", "17.01.2020",    "1",
        69126, "07.01.2020", "13.01.2020",   "0A",
        68753, "13.01.2020", "17.01.2020",   "1A",
        74928, "23.01.2020", "28.01.2020",   "2A",
        64720, "10.01.2020", "13.01.2020",    "1",
        48599, "16.01.2020", "22.01.2020",   "0A",
        68723, "07.01.2020", "13.01.2020",   "0A"
        )

df <- df %>% mutate(seqdat = seq(from=dmy(AufnDat), to=dmy(EntlDat), by="day"))
#> Error in seq.Date(from = dmy(AufnDat), to = dmy(EntlDat), by = "day"): 'from' muss Länge 1 haben

``` 
if I try the same for one row without mutate it works

``` r


## this works:

seq(from=dmy(df[1,2]), to=dmy(df[1,3]), by="day")
#> [1] "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23"
```
````

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Where is the difference and my fault ?

Comment: The mutate doesn't work as you put a vector with multiple values in the from and to. You need a single value. df[1,2] is a signle value (the one in first row, second column), so that is why that one does work. Did you try using min or max Augndat or Entldat? I do not know what you are trying to achieve exactly, so that makes it a bit hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` to  loop over each of the 'Aufndat', 'EntlDat' to get the sequence of 'Date' as `seq` is not vectorized for the `from`, `to`.  It would  be a `list` column, which we can `unnest` to expand the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(seqdat = map2(dmy(AufnDat), dmy(EntlDat), seq, by = 'day')) %>%
   unnest(c(seqdat))
```

Comment: Perfect. Better than expected. My next step is counting number of patients for each day. I must calculate how many patients are lying on each ward (Station) on each day. Now easy to solve by grouping and counting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @akruns answer we can store `seqdat` as list of lists:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(seqdat = list(seq(from=dmy(AufnDat), to=dmy(EntlDat), by="day"))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

df_new is now:

```
df_new

 # A tibble: 10 x 6
 # Groups:   ID [10]
     PLZ AufnDat    EntlDat    Stat1    ID seqdat    
    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <int> <list>    
 1 67067 22.01.2020 23.01.2020 1A        1 <date [2]>
 2 74936 21.01.2020 23.01.2020 1A        2 <date [3]>
 3 97999 21.01.2020 27.01.2020 0A        3 <date [7]>
 4 76669 15.01.2020 17.01.2020 1         4 <date [3]>
 5 69126 07.01.2020 13.01.2020 0A        5 <date [7]>
 6 68753 13.01.2020 17.01.2020 1A        6 <date [5]>
 7 74928 23.01.2020 28.01.2020 2A        7 <date [6]>
 8 64720 10.01.2020 13.01.2020 1         8 <date [4]>
 9 48599 16.01.2020 22.01.2020 0A        9 <date [7]>
10 68723 07.01.2020 13.01.2020 0A       10 <date [7]>
```

and

```
df_new$seqdat[1]
```

Returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23"
```